# Meter Load Center Combo a good option?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

We're beginning construction on some new property that will have a house and detached garage.

We're planning on building a permanent 200a power pole with the meter base separate from these two structures. We'll mount some outlets on the power pole for construction and then feed the well, garage, and house with separate wires coming from our power pole when needed.

Any thoughts regarding pros/cons of this plan?

Does this meter load center look like it would be a good option: [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B008KLSQC0/ref=ewc_pr_img_1?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008KLSQC0)

Would we be able to do everything from this box? Maybe a 100a breaker to the garage and then just a sub-feed lug kit to the house?

Comment: Unclear what you intend. Sub-feed lugs from the 200A panel, or sub-feed lugs from the 100A garage sub-panel?

Comment: @Ecnerwal - the sub-feed lugs from this 200a panel for the house.

Comment: @MikeS -- who is your electric utility?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - it's Klickitat PUD in WA.

Comment: @MikeS -- tip then: you'll want EUSERC compliant metering equipment

Comment: Thank you @ThreePhaseEel

Answer (score 2):

Yes, something like that will work. In fact, with the latest NEC you pretty much have to have something like that because you need a disconnect at the meter. However:

- Check with your utility before buying anything. Because this holds the meter, it is the one piece of equipment that the utility really has the power (pun intended) to control. Some utilities are "anything 200A that holds a standard round meter". Others have very detailed lists, sometimes long, sometimes very short, of what equipment you can use.
- You don't need that many spaces. Typically you need 2 spaces per building/well/etc., sometimes 4 spaces (depending on breaker size), plus a few spaces for local loads - e.g., 1 for a convenience circuit, 1 for outdoor lighting. A 40 space panel is more typically used when this panel is *also* the functional main panel for a building - e.g., if this is installed on the side of a house. Generally speaking I would recommend putting your functional main (though often technically a subpanel) indoors for convenience and durability, but that is a separate issue. That being said, you don't want to get an 8 space panel thinking that is exactly what you need right now (2 for well, 2 for house 2 for garage, 1 for lighting, 1 for convenience receptacle) and then be out of luck when the next device comes along (or another outbuilding). But if you only need 8 spaces now and each building will have a decent size subpanel then a 20 space ("space", not "circuit") panel should be plenty.

Comment: Thanks for all that manassehkatz! We were also looking the the same box with 20 spaces (https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00J3PJLT4/ref=ewc_pr_img_2?smid=ATVPDKIKX0DER&psc=1) It's nice because it's cheaper and smaller, but thought maybe there wouldn't be enough space inside or openings to handle the wiring needed for the house and garage.  Is it best to try to do it all from a single box or add a separate box/panel to the right of this to handle the house/garage?

Comment: Any good box (and Siemens makes good stuff) will have all the wire bending space, knockouts, etc. needed to handle any normal setup. You don't want to have to put in another box next to this one, but based on your description, this pole will be physically separate from all the buildings, so that is a non-issue. You also generally don't want to (and in fact actually *can't*) run lots of circuits to each building. What you actually do is run a 4-wire circuit (hot/hot/neutral/ground) to a subpanel in each building, and from that subpanel you run all the individual circuits you need for lighting,

Comment: receptacles, appliances, HVAC, etc. So 20 spaces (which is actually 10 double-pole circuits) is reasonable - 2 spaces for each building, a few extras for various things and still have half the spaces unused. Those unused spaces might stay unused forever (which is OK) or might eventually get used for other things as property usage changes.

Comment: My concern with the smaller box is getting the thick wires for the house and garage (4/0 AWG, right?) out of it cleanly. The smaller box only has three 2"+ knockouts and they're all concentrated in the bottom right corner (bottom, back, and right). Is that not going to be a problem? (I'm a complete newbie if you haven't figured). https://assets.new.siemens.com/siemens/assets/api/uuid:695794b0-b1d4-477a-ab3a-f53b71f410b2/sie-cs-mc2040b1200esc.pdf

Comment: Definitely consider Harper's recommendations. But as far as wire space - you only need 4/0 for the house. With a 200A service, all the other buildings will be breakered at well under 200A. 100A is 1 AWG aluminum, for example. And the well probably far less than that.

Comment: Hi @manassehkatz - Now I'm looking at a unit that only has 12 spaces (https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-200-Amp-12-Space-12-Circuit-Outdoor-Ring-Type-Overhead-Underground-Surface-Mount-Main-Lug-CSED-SC12L200S/100120834) , but will give us more room if we decide to do both the house and garage at 200a out of it. Am I just able to add lugs for multiple sub-panels to any panel like this?

Comment: Normally you get one set of lugs, by design. You don't want to feed 200A to more than one place because of wire cost and you can't effectively make use of the power. Typical is one large building, calculated at say 100A to 150A that gets the 200A lug feed. The remaining 50 to 100A is split to the other buildings, each with a breaker and much smaller wire. They could have 200A panels for many reasons, but power limited by feed breaker.

Answer (score 2):

### Wrong panel for the job, but not a good job

This is an all-in-one.  It is designed to bolt to the side of a house and be the only panel, with all circuits powered out of it.  All-in-ones are designed to be cheap.   That means stuff to builders because saving $300 a house, on 200 houses, pays a worker’s wage.

The right panel  for the job is what I call a "ranch panel".  It has:

- Optional, not recommended: meter pan
- main breaker
- **thru lugs** to carry full 200A onward to one building
- 4 to 12 breaker spaces intended for feeds to outbuildings

Why not the meter pan? Because of rapid changes happening in battery tech, informing EVs, V2H and grid-down preparedness for homes.  Batteries are the new generator.  This technology requires a smart disconnect between your distribution breakers and your meter pan.   When the meter pan is part of an all-in-one or ranch panel, it is impossible to insert the smart disconnect.  *Yes, there are meter collars, but those exist only at the pleasure of the power company, and they are NOT pleased at all, no sir Mr. Horse*.

And it is important to have parts of your homestead on the correct side of the disconnect. For instance a solar-ready meter pan would put the solar on the wrong side of the disconnect from the grid-forming inverter, meaning it would not be able to use solar to refill the battery.

Comment: Thanks @Harper! So, you'd recommend a separate box for the meter socket that is then connected to what you're calling a "ranch panel"? Can you please give me an example (link) to what you're recommending?

Comment: is this the type of device you're saying would be a better solution: https://www.platt.com/p/0582369/eaton/200a-ranch-panel-ch-type-22-kaic-surface/782116077380/cutcmber88b200bts

Comment: That's an "all-in-one", which will make future solar/battery/V2H tough.  A [meter pan is like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Eaton-200-Amp-Ringless-OH-UG-Single-Meter-Socket-UTRS213BE/202959693). A [ranch panel without meter is like this](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Square-D-Homeline-200-Amp-8-Space-16-Circuit-Outdoor-Main-Breaker-Load-Center-with-Feed-Thru-Lug-HOM816M200PFTRB/204836396).